# Heat map on 3D surface

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I numerically calculate eigenfunctions in a different program and upload them to *Mathematica* as a  .csv file. They are saved in a matrix form (*x*,*y* coordinates are indices, *z* coordinates are entry values). I would like to 'map' them back onto the original *3D* surface to produce a heat map on said surface. How would I do that?

Example of the surface:

```
R = 2;
f[s_] := {R*Cos[s/R], R*Sin[s/R], 0};
fT[s_] := {-Sin[s/R], Cos[s/R], 0};
fN[s_] := {-Cos[s/R], -Sin[s/R], 0};
fB[s_] := {0, 0, 1};
a = R/2;
fTheta[s_] := Pi/2;
fStrip[s_, t_] := f[s] + t*(fN[s]*Cos[fTheta[s]] - fB[s]*Sin[fTheta[s]])
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{fStrip[s, t]}, {s, 0, 2*Pi*R}, {t, -a, a}, Mesh -> None]]
```

Comment: The example you provided doesn't seem adequate for demonstrating the situation, but I think you'd want to use the [ColorFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) option.

Comment: Why is it not adequate? The code (should) generate a cylinder, by playing with the curve function `f` and angle function `fTheta` one can get loads of different 'ribbons'. 
My understanding is that to use the `ColorFunction`, I need to know what function the eigenfunction is. However, that is not possible as I get some generalizations of sines and cosines. Am I wrong?

Comment: How is that code going to generate a cylinder without any use of `Plot`, `Graphics`, or related functionality?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy one line... My bad!

Comment: Can you provide a sample .csv file that includes the points you would want to map to that surface? (uploading to Pastebin or something might be best)

Comment: How did you generate the eigenfunctions? What format do they have?

Comment: @user6014 : you can download the sample here http://leteckaposta.cz/430538099

Comment: @b3m2a1 : I compute them using finite difference method in IJulia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first create some random data to use:

```
randomdata = Flatten[Table[{{s, t}, RandomReal[]}, {s, 0, 2 Pi R, 2 Pi R/60}, {t, -a, a, 2 a/20}], 1];
```

This yields a list of the form

```
(* {{{0, -1}, 0.758619}, {{0, -(9/10)}, 0.471565}, {{0, -(4/5)}, 0.539463}, ... *)
```

i.e., points of the form `{ { s_value, t_value}, fn_value}`.  Note that `Table` produces a nested list by default, so I had to use `Flatten` to get it into the correct form.  Depending on the format of your original data, this may not be necessary.

Once you have your generated data in the correct form, you can use `Interpolation` to create a function that interpolates between them, and then feed this into `ParametricPlot3D` as a `ColorFunction`:

```
heatfn = Interpolation[randomdata];
ParametricPlot3D[{fStrip[s, t]}, {s, 0, 2*Pi*R}, {t, -a, a}, 
   Mesh -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, s, t}, ColorData["ThermometerColors"][heatfn[s, t]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I needed to convert my data, but in the end, it worked! :)